# unable to uninstall ghost program via wmi on powershell or cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, wmic

we have a ghost program Dell Command Update that is not uninstalling properly with WMI

it keeps returning the result code of --> **1603**

I try to run PowerShell and cmd as admin by right-clicking the program and entering my admin credentials.

the program does not exist under the control panel and looks to be an older version of the app that is left over in the registry preventing an update EXE of dell command update from running because it thinks an older version is still installed.

any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: `get-package *ghost* | uninstall-package`

Answer (score 1):

Had a simaler issue myself. I was still able to remove it from the settings menu. I found that getting the IdentifyingNumber was more effective with msiexec.exe. I was using this with a deployment system to remove and update Dell command update.

```
$APP_ID = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'Dell Command | Update for Windows Universal'"| Select-Object -Expandproperty IdentifyingNumber
if(-not $application){
    Write-host "DCU not Detected"
}else{
  Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $APP_ID /passive /qn /noreboot" -Wait

  write-host "DCU uninstalled"
}
```

hope this helps